# How do I unforce bot classes in TF2?

Tags: team-fortress-2

So, I forced the bots to have a certain class, but now I want to UNforce it but I don't know how to. I don't want to keep fighting soldiers in every training session I do. So how do I Unforce the bot class?

Comment: Nevermind, I found out I needed to type ""

Comment: Can you add your solution as a answer, that way other people with your problem can easily find it.

Answer (score 5):

*(Adding this as an answer to help anyone else encountering this)*

Just use the same command to force a class (`tf_bot_force_class`), but with the parameter `""` (double quotes). This is the default parameter without forcing any class.